# TypeScript: Using function parameter as JSON-key name

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, key, function-parameter

Following situation:

```
setFlags(data:any, key:string) {
    this.flags.key= data;
}
```

assumed data is `{'foo': 'is cool'}` and key is `'bar'` and the flags should look like:

```
{
    'bar': {'foo': 'is cool'}
}
```

is there a any simple solution for that purpose?

**EDIT:** A reply to the questions in the comments: It is going about a TypeScriptClass which will be used as a service, that stores flags.

```
@Injectable()
export class FormStoreService {
    flags:any = {};
    constructor() {}
    setFlags(data:any, key:string) {
        this.flags.key = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What is the problem with your code? What is `this` in the `setFlags` method, what is the type of `this.types`? You need to provide more info and explain what you are asking.

Comment: edited the question, see above

Comment: But what's the problem? Your code compiles without an error. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `foo.bar`, you are setting a property named `bar`. If the name of the property is dynamic, you should use the `foo[bar]` syntax.
So the `setFlags` method becomes

```
setFlags(data:any, key:string) {
 this.flags[key] = data;
}
```

Comment: yeat, I've already tried that successfully, I don't know why, I stupidly thought, with `[]` I would get an array :/ Thank you!